# Angle between vectors in the form of functions

Tags: cross-product

Find cos theta where theta is the angle between the vectors $$f(t)=t$$ and $$g(t)= t^2$$.

Should I solve this with the simple cos theta calculation formula on vectors.?I am confused.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Those functions are scalar functions, not something I would regard as vector-valued functions.  Are you supposed to take tangents to these curves or something?

Comment: Is there some sort of inner product on a space of functions to make sense of this? There is definitely context missing.

Comment: As @runway44 said, you need to specify the inner product to be used in this problem. Once you know that, you can use the usual formula that relates the inner product to the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

Comment: @Randall I don’t see where the question says “vector functions.” These are functions that are considered to be elements of some inner product space.